# find matching patterns in files linux

Tags: linux, bash, file, grep

I am trying to find matching strings between 2 files.
for example:
file 1:

```
A2M,0.00351888
A2M-AS1,0.00131091
A3GALT2,0.00966505
A4GALT,0.108364
AACS,0.0830823
AACSP1,0.00264056
AADACL2-AS1,0.0318584
AADACL4,0.00384096
AAED1,0.216966
```

file 2:

```
chr1    33772366    33786699    A3GALT2 1   -
chr22   43088126    43116876    A4GALT  1   -
chr12   125549924   125627871   AACS    1   +
chr5    178191863   178203277   AACSP1  1   -
chr1    12704565    12727097    AADACL4 1   +
chr9    99403532    99417599    AAED1   1   -
chr8    117950463   117956239   AARD    1   +
chr7    121713597   121784344   AASS    1   -
chr7    48211056    48687091    ABCA13  1   +
chr1    94458393    94586705    ABCA4   1   -
chr17   66970772    67057136    ABCA9   1   -
```

I want to extract the lines in file 2 that their 4th column is equal to the first column in file 1.
I wrote this command for it:

```
cat file | cut -d ',' -f1 | grep -wFf - file2 > match_file
```

But when it has another character - not [a-z] like: APCDD1L-AS1.
It takes only the APCDD1L and gives incorect results.
I read that grep -w works only with "real" words, so I guess this is the problem.
How can I fix it? (find the whole matching string)

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($4 in a)' FS="," file1 FS=" +" file2
chr1    33772366    33786699    A3GALT2 1   -
chr22   43088126    43116876    A4GALT  1   -
chr12   125549924   125627871   AACS    1   +
chr5    178191863   178203277   AACSP1  1   -
chr1    12704565    12727097    AADACL4 1   +
chr9    99403532    99417599    AAED1   1   -
```

I assumed that `file2` is space separated, `FS=" +"`. If it is in fact tab separated, set `FS="\t"`instead.

Comment: Just set `FS=" "` instead of `FS=" +"` or `FS="\t"` and it'll work no matter what white space is between the file2 fields. Alternatively set `-v FS='[[:space:]]+|,'` up front and it'll work for both files.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your data samples implying I can not simply grep any column as only one of them contains alphanumeric characters with that format. If thats the case this will do ( Bash compatible ) :

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f matched_output.txt
patterns=$( awk -F',' '{ print $1 }' Matching_patterns.txt )


while read pattern
do
    printf "Attempting $pattern"
    grep -F "$pattern" mytext.txt >> matched_output.txt && printf " - Success! \n" || printf " - Failed \n"

done <<< "$patterns"
```

#### Input files

[image]

#### Script running

[image]

#### Output file

[image]

Hope this is useful for you! Regards!

Comment: I've seen newcomers post images in their questions before but never seen anyone post images in an answer! Replace the images with copy/pasted text so people reading this can copy/paste that text to use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, let you avoid troubles with special symbols in names

```
firsts=( `cat f1 | cut -d',' -f1` ); for lines in ${firsts[@]}; do grep "${lines}" f2 >>output; done
```

Comment: So many issues... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice, google UUOC, google deprecated backticks, etc....